# CORS policy error occurring with GET mapping and working fine with POST mapping

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, cors

I have implemented a springboot project with multiple controller of GET and POST mapping, in this specific controller i have been facing cors policy issue as Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domain/abdm/v0.5/users/auth/on-fetch-return?key=5f7a535d-a3fd-416b-b069-c97d021fbacd' from origin 'http://localhost:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Where as it is working fine with other controller as POST along with GET mapping

```
Spring boot controller
public class ABDMSandboxController {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ABDMDTO> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ABDMResponseWriter abdmResponseWriter = new ABDMResponseWriter();
    
    @GetMapping("/on-fetch-return")
    public ResponseEntity<?> fetchModesreturn(@RequestParam String key) {
        System.out.println("on-fetch-return");
        if (concurrentMap.get(key) != null) {
            String FetchedResponse = concurrentMap.get(key).toString();
            String response = abdmResponseWriter.readFromFile(key);
            System.out.println(response);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(FetchedResponse);
        } else
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

```
AJAX call
 function getfetchmodesreturn()
 {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: GATEWAY_HOST+"/v0.5/users/auth/on-fetch-return?key=5f7a535d-a3fd-416b-b069-c97d021fbacd",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: 'application/json',
       headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken"),
           'accept':'*/*',
       },
       crossOrigin: true,
       success: function (data) {

           console.log("return data =====================",data);
           console.log(data);

       },// end success
       error: function (error) {
           console.log("On Error");
           console.log(error);
       }//end error
   });// end AJAX
 }
```

```
Spring security config
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    /**
     * Configure the behavior of Http Requests
     *
     * @param http - {@link HttpSecurity}
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
         CorsConfiguration conf = new CorsConfiguration();
         conf.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
         conf.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
         conf.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Collections.singletonList("*"));
         conf.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));

         UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
         source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", conf);
         return source;
    }
}
```

Looking for solution to resolve this cors policy issue. A have added a cors filter at global level, even tried adding @crosorgin("*")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include the spring-security config so that we can better understand the problem